# Insert row base on specific text and its occurrence

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a VBA code to insert rows below based on a specific text and its occurrence .

I am using the following code to do so

```
Sub try()
Dim c As Range
  For Each c In Range("A1:A100")
    If c.Value Like "*COLLECTION*" Then
       c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
  Next c
End Sub
```

1. I want to have the text BALANCE below the COLLECTION cell instead of blank row.
2. I want to insert the BALANCE row below the last COLLECTION entry, for example if there are two collections rows serially then I want to add the BALANCE row after the 2nd collection row. but with the above VBA code I am getting blank rows below to the each collection row.

My Collection and balance rows are in the column A

[Before macro Image kindly check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyOGP.jpg)
[image]

[After macro I want like this Image kindly check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrTth.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this using a loop from row 1 till last filled row in column `A`. Then having a boolean marker which is true while the cell value in current cell is like `"*COLLECTION*"` but false while not. So if the current cell is not like `"*COLLECTION*"` but the marker is true then the last cell above the current cell was like `"*COLLECTION*"`. Then insert a new row with  `"BALANCE"` if that cell is not already `"BALANCE"`.

```
Sub try()
 Dim c As Range
 Dim lRow As Long
 lRow = 1
 Dim lRowLast As Long
 Dim bFound As Boolean
 With ActiveSheet
  lRowLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Do
   Set c = .Range("A" & lRow)
   If c.Value Like "*COLLECTION*" Then
    bFound = True
   ElseIf bFound Then
    bFound = False
    If c.Value <> "BALANCE" Then
     c.EntireRow.Insert
     lRowLast = lRowLast + 1
     c.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "BALANCE"
     c.Offset(-1, 0).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
   End If
   lRow = lRow + 1
  Loop While lRow <= lRowLast + 1
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So your sample data within the pictures was bad since there are not blank rows. I've updated my code.

Comment: 1. I want the BALANCE text color should of BLACK.
2. I have values in DEMAND row and values in the COLLECTION row, now I want BALANCE = DEMAND-COLLECTION, there are two times collection for an entry so according to the occurrence of collection the balance should arise. Can you please let me know the macro code for that.

I have DEMAND values D1:S1 COLLECTION values from D2:S2 and the balance should be there in the next row.   kindly help me in this question                                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692884/get-values-on-a-row-based-on-two-or-more-rows-in-excel

Comment: For your first question see the edited code. Please note also the additional `lRowLast = lRowLast + 1` after inserting the row. This is necessary because the `lRowLast` was calculated before inserting new rows. Your other questions are additional. So please ask a new question. Show there the code *you* are using actual and the expected result in the BALANCE rows.

Answer (score 0):

That's typically the kind of cases you want to start from the last cell, because inserting a row will mess up all counters from what is below.

In other words, the elegant for each is not really a good idea. Too unpredictable. An ugly, old simple For Step -1 is the way to go. Something like :

```
Sub Macro1()
    For l = 100 To 1 Step -1
        If Trim(Cells(l, 1)) = "COLLECTION" And Trim(Cells(l + 1, 1)) = "DEMAND" Then
            Rows(CStr(l + 1) & ":" & CStr(l + 1)).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Cells(l + 1, 1) = "BALANCE"
        End If
    Next l
End Sub
```

Just tried on EXCEL 2013, seems to work as you want. There may be more elegant solutions, though.

EDIT : the idea is the following one :
_Begin by the last line(in fact, the last line cannot work, so one optimization could be to start from the prevo=ious one), and go to the first one
_If the line testes is "COLLECTION", and the next one is "DEMAND", then you need to insert a "BALANCE" line in between. It's done in 2 times, first insert an empty line, then add "BALANCE" in the newly created line.