# Get values on a row based on two or more rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have values in DEMAND row and values in the COLLECTION row, now I want BALANCE = DEMAND-COLLECTION, there are two times collection for an entry so according to the occurrence of collection the balance should arise. Can you please let me know the macro code for that.

I have DEMAND values D1:S1 COLLECTION values from D2:S2 and the balance should be there in the next row.

I came to this step after the solution I got from 
[Insert row base on specific text and its occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691318/insert-row-base-on-specific-text-and-its-occurrence)

I am using the following code

```
Sub try()
 Dim c As Range
 Dim lRow As Long
 lRow = 1
 Dim lRowLast As Long
 Dim bFound As Boolean
 With ActiveSheet
  lRowLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Do
   Set c = .Range("A" & lRow)
   If c.Value Like "*COLLECTION*" Then
    bFound = True
   ElseIf bFound Then
    bFound = False
    If c.Value <> "BALANCE" Then
     c.EntireRow.Insert
     lRowLast = lRowLast + 1
     c.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "BALANCE"
     c.Offset(-1, 0).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
   End If
   lRow = lRow + 1
  Loop While lRow <= lRowLast + 1
 End With
End Sub
```

[before macro check IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOEPy.jpg)

[After Macro I want this check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5oaq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I would use `SUMIF` applied with `FormulaR1C1` for that. The advantage is that we can set the formula in one step for the whole row.

```
Sub try()
 Dim c As Range
 Dim lRow As Long
 lRow = 1
 Dim lRowLast As Long
 Dim lRowDiff As Long
 Dim lRowPortion As Long
 lRowPortion = 1
 Dim bFoundCollection As Boolean
 With ActiveSheet
  lRowLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Do
   Set c = .Range("A" & lRow)
   If c.Value Like "*COLLECTION*" Then
    bFoundCollection = True
   ElseIf bFoundCollection Then
    bFoundCollection = False
    If c.Value <> "BALANCE" Then
     c.EntireRow.Insert
     lRowLast = lRowLast + 1
     Set c = c.Offset(-1, 0)
     c.Value = "BALANCE"
    End If
    If c.Value = "BALANCE" Then
     .Range(c, c.Offset(0, 18)).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
     .Range(c, c.Offset(0, 18)).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
     lRowDiff = c.Row - lRowPortion
     .Range(c.Offset(0, 3), c.Offset(0, 18)).FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=SUMIF(R[-" & lRowDiff & "]C1:RC1, ""*DEMAND*"", R[-" & lRowDiff & "]C:RC)" & _
      "-SUMIF(R[-" & lRowDiff & "]C1:RC1, ""*COLLECTION*"", R[-" & lRowDiff & "]C:RC)"
     lRowPortion = c.Row + 1
    End If
   End If
   lRow = lRow + 1
  Loop While lRow <= lRowLast + 1
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Should do. Please don't ask vague. Tell the concrete problems you have.